# LDAP: slapd and openldap

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

I have a Linux server on which some LDAP server is running.
It is started/stopped using command: start-slapd / stop-slapd

Does it mean that the slapd is the LDAP Server that is running? 
I also see OpenLDAP related files/installation on that server, but i am not sure if they are being used.

**Is my understanding correct - slapd can function independent of OpenLDAP?**

I need to setup similar LDAP Server on another machine with same LDAP data. Should i just install slapd, and import the data.

I am new to LDAP world, seeking advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'slapd' is the name of the OpenLDAP daemon. They aren't two different things.

Comment: On my new Linux Server i can see OpenLDAP files under /etc/openldap, but i cannot see slapd ('locate slapd' returns nothing). So how do i start openldap then?

Comment: Locate isn't finding anything named slapd likely because the locate database hasn't been updated since the files were created. slapd is the name of the openldap server, they are the same, and you already told us it's started using start-slapd. Another OSS project does the same thing - apache. The software is called apache but the binary that runs is httpd.

Comment: Its also possible that your Linux distros have different startup scripts for openldap, perhaps if eaches package manager included a custom one

Answer (score 0):

> *On my new Linux Server i can see OpenLDAP files under /etc/openldap, but i cannot see slapd ('locate slapd' returns nothing). So how do i start openldap then? – Jasper*

OK Jasper, try:

```
which slapd
```

... from your command-line.  If the slapd binary is located at a valid path, it will show you the fully qualified path to said file.

This is different from 'locate', as 'locate' works using a file manifest that must be updated periodically in order to be accurate.  Using 'which' will just search all "bin" or "sbin" locations and report the first one that is found.

> *Does it mean that the slapd is the LDAP Server that is running?*

To see if *slapd* is running, from the command-line, try one of these commands:

- *ps -ef | grep [s]lapd*
- *pidof slapd*

The first command above will show you more information about *slapd* IF it is running.  You'll see the process ID, the owning user of the process, the time, and the full set of arguments.

The second command just shows a process ID, which is nice and succinct.

> *I need to setup similar LDAP Server on another machine with same LDAP data. Should i just install slapd, and import the data.*

It depends.  Do these two servers ALWAYS need to be identical if a change is made? Or is one for Production use and one for Testing purposes?

If the data needs to be persistent across all servers at all times, then you need to configure what is called Replication.  You would define your 1st server as a master, and any subsequent servers as 'shadows' (a.k.a slaves), and configure the shadows to receive updates from the master automatically.  Replication is a fairly deep concept, so see the OpenLDAP Administrators Guide at http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/ for documentation on setting up, understanding and troubleshooting replication.

If the servers DO NOT need to be the same, then yes (as you said) just building a new server and importing data manually is perfectly fine.

I hope this helps...

Max